# What is wrong with my ST_Within query - query result contains point twice although it exists only once

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two point tables, `tab_1` and `tab_2`. I want to query all points from the first table that are probably the same points from the table 2. So i give the points from table 2 a buffer. Then I want to get the points from table 1 and query from table 2 within a 30 m buffer. My problem is, I get the points from table 1 and table 2 twice. But point 1 from table 1 exists only once and point 1 from table 2 also only once.

My query is:

```
 with 
    "points1" as 
    (
    select id, geom from tab_1
    )
    ,
    "points2" as 
    (
    select id, geom from tab_2
    )
select  "points1".*, "points2".* from "points1", "points2"
    where 
        st_within(st_transform("points1".geom, 31468), st_buffer(st_transform("points2".geom, 31468), 30)) = true;
```

| id_tab1 | geom | id_tab2 | geom | st_distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 767074270 | POINT (11.6968379 48.132722) | 16455 | POINT (11.69707 48.13265) | 19.041083533921977 |
| 767074270 | POINT (11.6968379 48.132722) | 16455 | POINT (11.69707 48.13265) | 19.041083533921977 |

The query should be give only one result:

| id_tab1 | geom | id_tab2 | geom | st_distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 767074270 | POINT (11.6968379 48.132722) | 16455 | POINT (11.69707 48.13265) | 19.041083533921977 |

Is my query wrong?

Comment: I would say that one of the points must appear twice in the base table.

Comment: Perhaps you have index corruption. Check if the point appears twice in `SELECT * FROM tab_1` or `SELECT * FROM tab_2`.

Comment: oh yes indeed tabl2 2 has twices, thx

Comment: Off topic, but: ST_DWithin might be a lot more efficient than buffer + within.

Comment: ok i try with this function also

Comment: ST_Dwithin ist approximatly 10x quicker than ST_Within with the ST_Buffer

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1. Query**

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab_1
  JOIN tab_2
    ON ST_DWithin 
       ( ST_Transform(tab_1.geom, 31468)
       , ST_Transform(tab_2.geom, 31468)
       , 30
       )
```

**STEP 2. Spatial index**

Most likely, the query cannot use the spatial index (even if it exists) and the function ST_DWithin() properly (ST_Transform() does not allow using an existing spatial index).

Solution - create new spatial indexes for EPSG:31468

```
CREATE 
 INDEX tab_1_geom_31468_idx
    ON tab_1
 USING GIST (ST_Transform(geom, 31468))
     ;

CREATE 
 INDEX tab_2_geom_31468_idx
    ON tab_2
 USING GIST (ST_Transform(geom, 31468))
     ;
```